# After initialization window view, programm generate millions of binding instances

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I programm app for using text templates.

I use Visual Studio 2017. .NET Framework 4.6.2. WPF and MVVM pattern.

So when i create instance for View, programm generate lots of instances with bindings or something else.

My code of command for create and show view:

```
public RelayCommand AddTemplate => addTemplate ??
(addTemplate = new RelayCommand(obj =>{
TemplateAddOrEditView templateAddView = new TemplateAddOrEditView(){
Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow};
TemplateAddOrEditViewModel templateAddViewModel = new
TemplateAddOrEditViewModel(SelectedGroup, templateAddView);
templateAddView.DataContext = templateAddViewModel;
templateAddView.Show();}));
```

And code of button in XAML

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Новый шаблон" Margin="3,0,3,3" FontSize="14" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding AddTemplate}"></Button>
```

[Before i press button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4QR2.png)

[After of pressing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqni3.png)

Comment: [MainWindow of App][1]

[Add Group for Template][2]

[SnapShoot when i press button][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3C4C.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN2KJ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/054nE.png

Comment: What's relevant here is source code of `TemplateAddOrEditView` (including xaml).

Comment: `public partial class TemplateAddOrEditView : Window{
public TemplateAddOrEditView(){
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new TemplateAddOrEditView();}}}`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0bPCx665
XAML

Comment: In constructor you provided you do this: `DataContext = new TemplateAddOrEditView();`. That means you create new instance of `TemplateAddOrEditView()` inside a constructor of `TemplateAddOrEditView()` itself, which causes recursive creation of new windows. You probably meant `DataContext = new TemplateAddOrEditView**Model**()`

Comment: @Evk man you save me. Great thanks!!!